Repeated button appears despite no code for it
I have this code where it's supposed to save an rgb combination to the database. A next button appears when i start entering the sequence and another one appears after i click confirm.
A screenshot was taken while entering the sequence 
This is afterwards
A screenshot after i clicked confirm
Here is the functions that handle confirmation:
ConfirmSequence (): (runs when clicking confirm)
window.confirmSequence = function () {
  const form = document.getElementById('clickForm');
 const formData = new FormData(form);
  fetch('save_sequence.php', {
       method: 'POST',
       body: formData
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => {
    const responseDiv = document.getElementById('sequenceDisplay');
    if (data.status === 'success') {
     responseDiv.innerHTML = `<p>${data.message}</p><button onclick="window.location.href='${data.next}'">Next</button>`;
     document.getElementById('confirmationButtons').style.display = 'none';
     } else {
      responseDiv.innerHTML = `<p>${data.message}</p>`;
                }
           })

Confirmation buttons part in the html page:
 <div id="confirmationButtons" style="display: none;">
            <input type="button" value="Confirm" onclick="confirmSequence()">
            <button onclick="reenterSequence()">Re-enter</button>
        </div>

I tried deleting a button from the relevant php page but that didn't work.

Why don't you try running it through the debugger? If you do, you can find exactly where the duplicate button is added. Normally you can open the debugger by pressing F12 or doing to the developer tab on the browser's menu.

Please edit your post and clarify what you question is.  What exactly are you asking? It would be helpful if you phrased your question in the form of a question with a ?

It seems there was an existing "next" button on the page already, and then you are adding <button onclick="window.location.href='${data.next}'">Next</button> to responseDiv.innerHTML.

When I reproduced your code, only one "Next" button is showing up (after clicking on confirm). You probably left out the part, where the other button is/is added.
